# Fusion Table layer InfoWindow showing all vertices in geometry field

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

this is my first post here so I apologize if I make a newbie faux pas.

I've got a [Google Fusion Table layer](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Bgo94POIxKwQOOltuFbaAW6CpjQqPvYLVSqXuLk) that I have on top of a map.  I created it by importing a KML file.  Everything works great, but last week I realized that the InfoWindow is now displaying all of the vertices of the relevant polygon in the geometry field.

The strange thing is that these vertices do not display in the actual Fusion Table but only on the layer on top of the map.  I suspect something might be going on with the JavaScript code, which I am very new to, or perhaps the new API for the Fusion Tables.

I removed the body section to get around some formatting issues on this page, but here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
                <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
                <title>Georgia Areas</title>

                <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 


                <style type="text/css">
                                html { height: 100% }
                                body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
                                #map_canvas { height: 100%; weight: 100% }
                                #search-panel {
                                                position: absolute;
                `                               top: 10px;
                                                left: 50%;
                                                margin-left: -180px;
                                                width: 350px;
                                                z-index: 5;
                                                background-color: #fff;
                                                padding: 5px;
                                                border: 1px solid #999;
                                }
                                #address {
                                                width: 345px;
                                }
                                #instruction {
                                                position:  fixed;
                                                float:  right;
                                                bottom:  10px;
                                                right:  20px;
                                                width: 375px;
                                                z-index: 4;
                                                background-color: #fff;
                                                padding: 7px;
                                                border: 1px solid #999;
                                                font-family:"Arial";
                                }
                                p.small {font-size: small}
                </style>

                <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyARy6zbLmjvq3uaPjI--s45afA0LA-ynnA&amp;sensor=false">
                </script>


                <script type="text/javascript">

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                var input = document.getElementById('address');

                var geocoder;
                var gaCentroid;
                var gaBounds;
                var myMap;


                function myclick(num) {
                                google.maps.event.trigger(markers[num], "click");
                }


                function initialize() {

                                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();                          

                                gaCentroid = new google.maps.LatLng(32.900000, -83.22671);

                                gaBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                                                new google.maps.LatLng(30.34,-85.652),
                                                new google.maps.LatLng(35.01,-80.85)
                                );

                                var mapOptions = {
                                                center: gaCentroid,
                                                zoom: 8,
                                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                };

                                myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
                                                mapOptions);

                                var lyr = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                                                query: {
                                                                select: 'geometry',
                                                                from: '1Bgo94POIxKwQOOltuFbaAW6CpjQqPvYLVSqXuLk'
                                                },
                                                styles: [{
                                                                polygonOptions: {
                                                                                fillColor: '0xDEEBF7',
                                                                                fillOpacity: 0.1
                                                                }
                                                }]
                                });

                                lyr.setMap(myMap);  

                }


                function codeAddress() {
                                var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
                                geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, function(results, status) {
                                                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                                                myMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                                                myMap.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport)
                                                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                                                map: myMap,
                                                                                position: results[0].geometry.location
                                                                });
                                                } else {
                                                                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                                                }
                                });
                }

                function reCenter() {
                                var currentCenter = myMap.getCenter();
                                google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');
                                myMap.setCenter(currentCenter);
                }


</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the content shown in the infowindow.

See [this page](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171216?hl=en) in the Fusion Tables Help

Comment: This Help Page seems to apply to the InfoWindow that displays in the Fusion Tables.  That InfowWindow displays as desired.  The problem is that the InfoWindow is not the same on the Google Map I am placing the layer over.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the `templateId` to have the same content for the infoWindow.

Add this to the options passed to the layer:

```
templateId:2
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate a little bit?  I can't find any documentation on templateID.  Is this option added to the FusionTablesLayerOptions or to the InfoWindowOptions?

Comment: to the FusionTablesLayerOptions. You'll find a tutorial [here](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1244603?hl=en&) . To see which template currently is used , go to https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Bgo94POIxKwQOOltuFbaAW6CpjQqPvYLVSqXuLk and select the tab "Map of geometry" . Click on the small downwards arrow beside the label and select "publish". A window opens, here click on "Get HTML and Javascript". You'll see that there is the templateId-option of the layer set to **2**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the code to reference another Fusion Tables Layer.  All I changed was the ID.  This seems to work with the new layer, but I still do not know what happened to display the geometry in the InfoWindow.

If it happens again, I will most likley attempt Dr.Molle's suggestion.